# Calling a function in a different python file using Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm working on a project for which I need to call functions from several python files to use in one main program. All of the programs in question are notebooks in the same directory in Google Colab. I am having trouble being able to call the functions I need and I haven't been able to find a solution that works. I've tried simply `from InterpolateData import LoadandInterp` where `InterpolateData` is the file name where the function `LoadandInterp` is stored. This is what I currently have:

```
from google.colab import files
import sys
sys.path.append( "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks")
import InterpolateData
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

#get, normalize and interpolate data

#SpectralHighData
temperatureList=np.arange(25.0,46.0,1.0)
interpList=np.arange(25.0,45.0,0.1)
pathBefore="/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Original Data/High Temperatures/Spectral_high/CdTe Spectra Interpolated "
pathAfter="C.csv"

interpolated=InterpolateData.LoadandInterp(temperatureList, interpList, pathBefore, pathAfter)
```

Everything that I've tried returns an error along the lines of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'InterpolateData'`

Does anyone know a way I can get this to work? Surely, there is a way?

**Edit:** Before the previous code, I have code to mount my google drive and change the directory to where the files are stored. It looks like this:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)

!ls "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks"
%cd "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks"
```

Comment: have you tried changing your working directory as opposed to adding to the path?

Comment: I've tried adding a change directory line after mounting my google drive. I'm not sure if that is what you mean because I'm fairly new with this language and colab. I'll post that chunk of code as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this in the future: I was able to find a solution, eventually.

In order to access another program, the program file must be a .py file and it must be in a folder that also contains a file called `_init_.py`. The `_init_.py` can be completely empty.

Once you have the files set up, change your directory to the folder with your 'module' program(s) using `%cd 'filepath'`. You can then import your module using `import filename`. The functions in your other program are now accessible through `filename.function`.